# Scala/Slick JDBC encoding configuration with typesafe config

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, utf-8, slick

I am building a Scala application using [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/database.html) where I load my `MySQLDriverbackend` with `val db = Database.forConfig("mysql.dev")` and where my "application.conf" file looks like

```
mysql = {
dev = {
    dataSourceClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
    properties = {
      databaseName = "test"  
      user = "user"
      password = "password"
      serverName = "localhost"
      portNumber="3306"
    }
  }
}
```

I am successfully saving data to my database which uses a default utf-8 encoding. However when trying to save the character 泗 I ended in my database with the dreaded `?` instead of input character.

I think I failed to declare that my connection needs to use UTF-8, however I couldn't find the option in the documentation of [`forConfig`](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/api/index.html#slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef@forConfig(String,Config,Driver,ClassLoader):Database).

Do you know how I can fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to provide `url` parameter?

Comment: This might be an alternative way to pass the DB information, but it currently works as is.

Comment: If you could use `url` parameter then adding parameters `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` should resolve the issue.

Comment: In the table/column, be sure to have `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  `utf8` is not sufficient for all of Chinese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MySQL, adding parameters `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` in your connection URL should solve the issue ie.

```
jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<database>?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

You could use this [link](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/database.html#using-a-database-url) to configure url.

Comment: Thanks for that, it allowed to check everything else was actually working. I will still post what I did to keep my file structure.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Sudhir's answer that keeps the same file structure is to set`properties` to:

```
properties = {
      databaseName = "test"  
      user = "user"
      password = "password"
      serverName = "localhost"
      portNumber="3306"
      characterEncoding="utf8"
      useUnicode=true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

utf8mp4 emoji issue

for spring-boot

[Insert emoji does not work with spring-boot and MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229141/insert-emoji-does-not-work-with-spring-boot-and-mariadb/49421790#49421790)

`spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/config.html

Because slick supply HikariCP pool,I think hikari pool may solve this issue then try

```
mysql_orginal = {
  connectionPool = "HikariCP"
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  connectionInitSql ="SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/table?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
  keepAliveConnection = true
  user = "root"
  password = "123456"
  numThreads = 4
  poolName="mysql_orginal_pool"
}
```

`val ORIGIN_DB = Database.forConfig("mysql_orginal")`

`libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.0"`

it works

demo: https://github.com/cclient/ScalaMysqlSync

ref:

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/database.html#databaseconfig

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick-hikaricp/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/hikaricp/HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/4674b977d9eeaf825d57808d48dbbfc37e47858c/doc/src/config.md#monitoring-indexmonitoring

Comment: This answer might be better if you edit it to quote the relevant parts from the tutorial you have linked to - ideally translated into English if possible :)