# Insert emoji does not work with spring-boot and MariaDB

Tags: spring-boot, utf-8, mariadb, utf8mb4

I would like to insert emoji like  in mariaDB database but I always get a sql error.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
12-01-2018 16:01:44.466 [Executor - Migration - 1] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:129 - SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: 22007
12-01-2018 16:01:44.466 [Executor - Migration - 1] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions:131 - (conn:498) Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xB3\xF0\x9F...' for column 'notes' at row 1
Query is: insert into customer (backend_archiving_date, backend_creation_date, backend_update_date, genius_client_id, address, birthday, city, company_name, country, email, fidelity_account_id, first_name, last_name, notes, phone, siret, zip_code, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), parameters [<null>,'2018-01-12 15:01:44.454','2018-01-12 15:01:44.454',2159,'20 rue raspail
',<null>,'LEVALLOIS PERRET','','FRANCE','','00c55854-99df-4db1-88b9-34f7e5608477','claude','amsellem','','','','92300','2152ed7d-80a1-4305-9fcb-4e21f5947e32']
```

I my Maria db, the table has

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and the field "notes" has also "utf8mb4 - Unicode" charset.

When I insert via a sql query

```
update customer set notes='' where id = 'f5920301-5ee0-4d58-a786-d4701d9e9d73';
```

it works, but when I want to insert emoji with my program (spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate) I always get the error (see stacktrace).

**EDIT**

FYI Here is the creation script

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
`id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
`notes` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`zip_code` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`company_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`siret` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`fidelity_account_id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`backend_creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
`backend_update_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`backend_archiving_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`genius_client_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
KEY `fk_customer_fidelity_account` (`fidelity_account_id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_fidelity_account` FOREIGN KEY (`fidelity_account_id`) REFERENCES `fidelity_account` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the connection params (spring-boot application.yml)

```
# Datasource configuration
spring:
  datasource:
    type: "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
    url: "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/genius_back useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF8"
    hikari:
      driver-class-name: "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
      username: "mariadb"
      password: "mariadb"
      minimum-idle: 5
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      validation-query: "SET NAMES utf8mb4"
  jackson:
     serialization:
      write_dates_as_timestamps: false
  http:
     client-user-agent: "Genius"
     multipart:
      max-file-size: 100Mb
      max-request-size: 150Mb
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OKAY,
I found the problem.

The solution was to add

```
spring:
  datasource:
     connectionInitSql: "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'"
```

in the application.yml.

`connectionInitSql` is used by HikariCP when it open the connection.

Comment: So, should the "validation query" be removed?

Comment: Yes, it can be removed. I deleted it and it works. Thanks Rick.

Answer (score 7):

`spring-boot` 2.0.0.RC2

`mysql` 5.7.14

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\xAD' for column 'title' at row 1
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2484)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
... 68 more
```

`spring.datasource.connectionInitSql`  is not work for me

i see hikari.pool

then try

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionInitSql=SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

it works so do

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

ref https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby

Answer (score 4):

For Spring boot with tomcat embedded use:

`spring.datasource.tomcat.initSQL = SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`

Answer (score 1):

When you are connecting, set the charset to utf8mb4.  Please provide the connection details.

Use utf8mb4 on the column(s) in the table.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can verify that the *column*, not just the table *default* is utf8mb4.

Comment: I added the creation script. Note that I can add emoji with a sql query like `update customer set notes='' where id = 'f5920301-5ee0-4d58-a786-d4701d9e9d73';
`, so this is not a db problem. The problem may be at the spring/hibernate level...?